# ¿ Cómo ocultar/pausar un botón para evitar que se presione?

Tags: java, android, timer

Tengo un gran pequeño problema, tengo un layout con **2 botones "iniciar" y "timers"** y 3 parámetros a introducir, (**numeros de rondas, minutos y descansos**) una vez introducido esos valores le das a **iniciar** y empieza una cuenta atrás, así de sencillo. **Lo que pasa que desde que le das a iniciar y empieza la cuenta atrás hay un audio que dura 10 segundos** y si el usuario *clicka* el boton **iniciar** en esos 10 segundos, cuando empieza la cuenta atrás se raya y mucho.

Lo que he encontrados son 2 soluciones: hacer desaparecer el boton iniciar con `View.GONE` o hacer aparecer un `dialog` encima para evitar que el usario pueda clikarlo. **pero NO SOY CAPAZ de hacer que pase eso antes del audio** ¿ cómo lo hago ? lo he intentado todo en zonas clave.

AYUDAS:

La función de empezar el audio se llama `public void estamos_contigo()` lo  del boton start es `iniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()..`  y la función que hace que el programa espere 10 segundos mientras suena el audio es `public void esperar(int seconds)` . Puedo proporcionar lo que queráis, sé que es muy largo y llevo más de 5 largas horas intentado hacerlo sin éxito.

Gracias de antemano.

`public class Three_fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {`

```
private TextView crono;
private TextView View2;
private TextView View3;
private TextView View4;

private ImageView spotify;

private Button iniciar;
private Button ajustar;
private Button detener;
private Button asaltos;
private Button user_minutos;
private Button des_segundos;


private Button incrementar;

private static final String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d:%02d";

//Asaltos
private int segundos;
private int minutos;
private int numero_asaltos;

//Tiempos
private int tiempo;
private int tiempo1;
private int tiempo_descanso;
private int tiempo_descanso1;
private int auxiliar;

private CountDownTimer timer;

//El onCreateView es el metodo que nos enlaza el .java con el fragment o xml
//Se implementa de este modo
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.three_tab, container, false);

    getActivity().setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    //En los fragments tenemos que instanciar los objetos aqui
    if (v != null) {
        crono = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.crono);
        //Botones
        iniciar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.iniciar);
        ajustar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.ajustar);
        detener = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.detener);
        asaltos = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        user_minutos = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button7);
        des_segundos = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button8);

        //Componentes de la interfaz
        View2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        View3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        View4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        spotify = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.spotify);

        spotify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Intent intencion = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.spotify.music");
                    startActivity(intencion);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Instala Spotify para acceder a tu playlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        asaltos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setNumberAsaltos();
            }
        });
        user_minutos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setDuracionAsaltos();
            }
        });
        des_segundos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                   setDuracionDescansos(); }
        });

        //Cambiamos las fuentes
        String font_path = "fonts/TitilliumWeb-BoldItalic.ttf";
        Typeface TF = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),font_path);
        View2.setTypeface(TF);
        View3.setTypeface(TF);
        View4.setTypeface(TF);
        iniciar.setTypeface(TF);
        ajustar.setTypeface(TF);
        detener.setTypeface(TF);
        asaltos.setTypeface(TF);
        user_minutos.setTypeface(TF);
        des_segundos.setTypeface(TF);
        crono.setTypeface(TF);
```

// AQUÍ ES UN PUNTO IMPORTANTE, DONDE EMPIEZA INICIAR

```
        iniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (numero_asaltos == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Especifica el número de asaltos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (minutos == 0 || segundos == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Especifica la duración del entrenamiento", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return;
                }



                    //A partir de aquí trabajamos con todos los datos
                tiempo = (minutos * 60);
                tiempo1 = tiempo;
                tiempo_descanso = segundos;
                tiempo_descanso1 = tiempo_descanso;

                //Cambiamos los editText por el cronometro
                asaltos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                user_minutos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                des_segundos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                View2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                View3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                View4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                crono.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                iniciar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                detener.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                try {
                    //SONIDO:falta campana y la cuenta atrás
                    AudioManager am2 = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    int result = am2.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);
                    if(result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED){
```

// AQUÍ ES UN PUNTO IMPORTANTE, DONDE HAGO LA LLAMADA AL AUDIO, Y QUIERO QUE //ANTES DE ESE AUDIO OCULTE BOTÓN , POR ESO LO HE PUESTO ANTES DE ESTA //INSTRUCCIÓN SI ÉXITO.

```
                        estamos_contigo();
                    }else  {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Deshabilitada la opción de control de audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    esperar(10);
                    campana();
                    am2.abandonAudioFocus(null);
                    asalto();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        detener.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                detener.setVisibility(GONE);
                iniciar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                timer.cancel();
            }
        });

        ajustar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    timer.cancel();
                    asaltos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    user_minutos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    des_segundos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    View2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    View3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    View4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    crono.setVisibility(GONE);

                    iniciar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    detener.setVisibility(GONE);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ajusta los timers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return v;
}

public void asalto() throws InterruptedException {

    timer = new CountDownTimer(tiempo1 * 1000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            crono.setText("" + String.format(FORMAT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));


        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if (numero_asaltos - 1 != auxiliar) {
                try {
                    auxiliar = auxiliar + 1;
                    //SONIDO
                    AudioManager am4 = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    int result = am4.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);
                    if(result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED){
                        raw_acabado();
                    }else  {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Deshabilitada la opción de control de audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    esperar(3);
                    am4.abandonAudioFocus(null);
                    descanso();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                auxiliar = 0;
                //SONIDO
                AudioManager am1 = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                int result = am1.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);
                if(result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED){
                    final_entrenamiento();
                }else  {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Deshabilitada la opción de control de audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

public void descanso() throws InterruptedException {

    timer = new CountDownTimer(tiempo_descanso1 * 1000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            crono.setText("" + String.format(FORMAT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            try {
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                int result = am.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);
                if(result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED){
                    //SONIDO
                    preparado_siguiente();
                }else  {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Deshabilitada la opción de control de audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                esperar(7);
                campana();
                am.abandonAudioFocus(null);
                asalto();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
//A partir de aquí introduciremos todas las funciones que reproduzcan los mensajes
//de la parte del cronómetro

public void final_entrenamiento() {
    MediaPlayer sonido = MediaPlayer.create(this.getActivity(), R.raw.finalentrenamiento);
    sonido.start();
}

public void preparado_siguiente() {
    MediaPlayer sonido = MediaPlayer.create(this.getActivity(), R.raw.preparadosiguiente);
    sonido.start();
}

public void raw_acabado() {
    MediaPlayer sonido = MediaPlayer.create(this.getActivity(), R.raw.rawnacabado);
    sonido.start();
}
```

// AQUÍ ES UN PUNTO IMPORTANTE, DONDE EMPIEZA EL AUDIO, JUSTO ANTES DE QUE // EMPIECE ESTE AUDIO ES DONDE QUIERO OCULTAR EL BOTON "iNICIAR"

```
public void estamos_contigo() {

    MediaPlayer sonido = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.cuenta_atras);
    sonido.start();
}

public void campana() {
    MediaPlayer sonido = MediaPlayer.create(this.getActivity(), R.raw.campana_3s);
    sonido.start();
}

public void esperar(int seconds){
    try{



        Thread.sleep(seconds*1000);

    }catch (Exception e){}
}



//Esto es lo que empleamos con los dialogs
private void setNumberAsaltos() {
    NumberPicker mynumberPicker = new NumberPicker(getActivity());
    //mynumberPicker.setBackgroundColor();
    //mynumberPicker.setScrollBarSize();
    //mynumberPicker.setBackgroundColor();
    mynumberPicker.setMaxValue(15);
    mynumberPicker.setMinValue(0);

    NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener myValChangedListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            asaltos.setText("" + newVal);
            numero_asaltos = newVal;
        }
    };
    mynumberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(myValChangedListener);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(mynumberPicker);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.num_asaltos_f).setIcon(R.drawable.rudeboys_icon);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.listo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

private void setDuracionAsaltos() {
    NumberPicker mynumberPicker = new NumberPicker(getActivity());
    mynumberPicker.setMaxValue(15);
    mynumberPicker.setMinValue(0);

    NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener myValChangedListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            user_minutos.setText(newVal + " min");
            minutos = newVal;
        }
    };
    mynumberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(myValChangedListener);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(mynumberPicker);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.dur_asaltos_f).setIcon(R.drawable.rudeboys_icon);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.listo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

private void setDuracionDescansos() {
    NumberPicker mynumberPicker = new NumberPicker(getActivity());
    mynumberPicker.setMaxValue(59);
    mynumberPicker.setMinValue(0);

    NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener myValChangedListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            des_segundos.setText(newVal + " sec");
            segundos = newVal;
        }
    };
    mynumberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(myValChangedListener);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(mynumberPicker);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.dur_descansos_f).setIcon(R.drawable.rudeboys_icon);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.listo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
}
```

}

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que 'se raya'? Veo demasiado código. Explica tu problema mejor, y haz referencia al código que falla.

Comment: Bandicoot, esta en lo que he llamado "AYUDAS" el audio que me interesa esta en la función ``public void estamos_contigo()`` y lo que quiero es que **justo antes** de sonar ese audio ( que es cuando presionas el botón de **iniciar**) dicho botón desaparezca.

Comment: Lo de hacer desaparecer el botón es para evitar ser pulsado después , porque se raya mi App si lo hago y con "rayar" me refiero a que sale un cartel diciendo que ha surgido un problema.

Comment: Voy a editar aún más poniendo comentarios donde se debe mirar dentro del código pero en "AYUDAS" está. Gracias.

Comment: Intenta con tuboton.setEnable(false) así se desactiva el botón al pulsar no desaparece solo ya no se puede pulsar

Comment: Lo he probado pero hace efecto cuando se acaba la cuenta atrás. Mi programa no me deja hacer nada antes del audio y no sé porqué, lo estoy  poniendo antes de ``estamos_contigo();``

Comment: O sencillamente me lo desactiva para 1 click pero si le doy 10 seguidos se raya igual.

Comment: Cuando lo necesites de nuevo usa true en vez de false ...

Answer (score 1):

> ¿ Cómo ocultar/pausar un botón para evitar que se presione?

Para ocultarlo simplemente cambia su visibilidad

```
boton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

pero para no influir en cambiar la UI, simplemente puedes deshabilitarlo

```
boton.setEnabled(false);
```

con esto también deshabilita lo listener que tenga configurados.

---

Para evitar que el boton se raye al presionarlo en varias ocasiones, podrias permitir su cambio mediante una variable

```
private boolean botonDesactivado = false;


boton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!botonDesactivado){ //Revisa si el botón esta habilitado.
            boton.setEnabled(false); //Deshabilita boton.
            botonDesactivado = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: el problema es que si lo pongo a false tal como dices, si lo pulso muchas veces por ejemplo 8 veces se raya de todas formas.

Comment: se "raya", a que te refieres amigo?

Comment: He puesto 14 veces la línea de false y se ve (muy raro) que cuanto más pongas, más veces puede dar el usuario al boton sin que se raye, es decir, si pones 14 veces setEnabled(false) doy aprox 10 veces al boton start y no pasa nada , pero si le doy 16 sí se raya. ¿ es logico?

Comment: ok agrego actualización, no deberías desabilitar varias veces el botón  setEnabled(false) , deberías limitar en caso de estar deshabilitado no necesitas volver a deshabilitarlo.

Comment: Elena, estoy poniendo que boton desactivado antes de la linea ``estamos_contigo()`` que es cuando empieza el audio y debe estar desactivado el botón, ¿ puede que el fallo sea el Tread.sleep()? Porque he hecho lo que me has puesto sin éxito, se me raya (me sigue saliendo mensaje de que se ha detenido o similar) En el log no me sale nada, solo me sale: **E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb92c7c48**

Comment: Actualizo: no, he puesto system.clock y nada, se raya igual, puedes abrir chat?

Comment: Elena, tengo un bottom bar en la aplicacion ya que es un fragment, y si **toco cualquier cosa del bottom bar también se me crashea** ¿ se puede sencillamente prohibir al usario de cualquier touch en la pantalla?

Comment: voy a abrir otra pregunta mejor

Answer (score 1):

Ejecuta la función `estamos_contigo()` encapsulado en un `if` con un booleano de control. La primera vez que ejecutes el evento `onClick` pon el `boolean` a `true` y si lo vuelves a pulsar no volverá a ejecutarse el sonido, dado que saltará la condición.

Declara el booleano fuera de la función.

```
static boolean ejecutado = false;
```

... luego en el evento `onClick`:

```
if(ejecutado == false){
   estamos_contigo();
   ejecutado = true;
}
```

Cuando finalice el *Timer* vuelve a poner la variable `ejecutado` a `false`. Al ser `static` podrás acceder a él desde cualquier parte.

Comment: No se me reproduce nunca el sonido 2 veces, lo que pasa es que: 1.  Relleno 3 cuadros necesarios con minutos, segundos y rondas. 2. Le doy a start 3. suena un audio durante 10 segundos ( y logicamente pauso 10 segundos el programa para que no empiece el crono hasta que acabe el audio) 4. **El problema es durante esos 10 segundos, que no quiero que el usuario al pulsar otra vez el boton start se crashee la App**

Comment: El error posiblemente esté entonces en el Tread.sleep() que paras el hilo de ejecución y cuando el usuario interactua con el botón, al estar el hilo parado, posiblemente te lance el error. Puedes poner el mensaje de la consola de error?

Comment: Solo me sale **E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb92c7c48**

Comment: Esoty poniendo iniciar.setEnabled(false) antes del audio que es ``estamos_contigo();`` pero se ve que no va T.T y es tan sencillo lo que debe hacer que no comprendo.

Comment: Yo me plantearía sustituir el Thread.sleep(), pon una condición para el inicio despues de que hayan pasado los diez segundos. Cuando termine el timer marca un booleano a true y que se pueda comenzar a pulsar los botones, o cuando pulses iniciar pon todos los componentes a enabled(false) y cuando termine el Timer vuelves a colocar enabled(true) por ejemplo.

Comment: He quitado el thread y he puesto SystemClock, el problema es mientras suena el audio, después esta todo claro , despues todo funciona, una vez acabe el sonido esta solucionado todo. **El problema es mientras está sonando el audio de 10 segundos** que necesito que no pueda apretar nada.

Comment: De todas formas, Jose, he abierto una pregunta porque necesito que el usuario no pueda tocar nada de la pantalla, pues tengo un bottombar y tambien se me crashea por ahi, simplemente necesito que no se pueda tocar la pantalla, o que salga un dialog para evitar que puedan ser presionados los botones... alguna solucion.

Comment: Pues si puedes crear un dialog con el contador de 10 segundos y que a los 10 segundos se quite, asi evitarás posiblemente que el usuario pulse cualquier botón